# Magento front and backend suddenly displaying in plain text

Tags: magento-1, frontend, backend

my website is suddenly displaying in plain text, my backend as well. I'm running Magento 1 still. I tried restoring a back up from before the incident happened, nothing changed.
I made sure the ip_config table in my database is not missing any /. I also checked on the css stylesheet link, i do not have any missing / either.
i'm starting to run out of options here, is there anything else i can try to fix this problem?

Comment: show some screenshot

Comment: Problem solved. Issue was with the permissions on css and media files. I checked the error log and found all access denied logs. whats mind blowing is that these permissions were changed.